# Checking that a class reference is returned with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Say I've defined a Ruby class along these lines:

```
class Blah
  def self.ref_class
    ::Other::Thing
  end
end
```

`.ref_class` returns a class reference (that's what it's called, right?).  How do I test this method with RSpec?

Answer (score 5):

### Examples

#### To ensure it is a Class

```
expect(Blah.ref_class.class).to eq(Class)
```

#### To ensure it extends another Class or includes other Modules

```
expect(Blah.ref_class.ancestors).to include(SuperClass)
```

#### To ensure it is a specific class

Use Amadan's answer. Here's an exerpt.

```
expect(Blah.ref_class).to eq(::Other::Thing)
```

#### To ensure it is an instance of a specific class

```
expect(Blah.new).to be_an_instance_of(Blah)
```

#### To ensure it is an instance of a specific class or one of its subclasses

```
expect(Blah.new).to be_an(Object) # or one of `be_a` `be_a_kind_of`
```

### Background

#### Class

In Ruby, class of a class is Class.

```
class Sample
end

Sample.class #=> Class
Sample.class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

#### Ancestors

In Ruby, extended Classes and included or prepended Modules are part of ancestors list.

```
module IncludedModule
end

module PrependedModule
end

class Sample
  include IncludedModule
  prepend PrependedModule
end

Sample.ancestors #=> [PrependedModule, Sample, IncludedModule, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

#### Instance

In Ruby, class of an instance is the class.

```
Sample.new.class #=> Sample
```

To check if an instance is exactly of specified class.

```
Sample.new.class == Sample #=> true # what be_an_instance_of checks.
Sample.new.instance_of? Sample #=> true
Sample.new.class == IncludedModule #=> false
Sample.new.instance_of? IncludedModule #=> false
```

To check if an instance's class is exactly specified class or one of its subclasses.

```
Sample.new.kind_of? IncludedModule #=> true # Same as #is_a?
Sample.new.class.ancestors.include? IncludedModule #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a normal return value, like `"hello"`; but of class `Class`. So just check that the function returns the value it is supposed to. Where you'd `expect(Greeting.in_morning).to eq "hello"`, in this case, `expect(Blah.ref_class).to eq ::Other::Thing`.